# How to create tree table in react js

Tags: reactjs, antd

How to create tree table dynamically

if on click in icon plus add rows or add subrows

example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie3dY.png)

Comment: check my repo [here](https://github.com/amansadhwani/all-features-react/blob/master/src/components/FolderStructure/Accordin.tsx)

Comment: Your question is way too broad and in its current state asking to develop a whole feature from scratch. You need to show what you have tried so far and accompany it with code we can test.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You may have to create a component that renders the tree structure recursive manner.